# Laravel4 routing to method with arguments

Tags: php, laravel-4

I just started working with Laravel after CodeIgniter and there some things that just confuse me.

I have a `PagesController` which takes care of displaying static pages such as about, contact, privacy etc'.

Now, instead of creating 3-4 methods on my `PagesController`, I would like to create one method thats called `ShowPage($which) { }` and knows which page to display.

The thing is > I can't understand the route issue:

```
Route::get('about','PagesController@ShowPage'); <--- I need to pass 'about' here
Route::get('contact','PagesController@ShowPage');
Route::get('about','PagesController@ShowPage');
```

Is that possible or should I need to create a method for each one of these cases?

Here is my exact code:

Controller:

```
class PagesController extends BaseController {

    function showPage($which) {
        echo $which;
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('about','PagesController@showPage');
Route::get('contact','PagesController@showPage');
Route::get('about','PagesController@showPage');`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the route directly inside your controller by using

```
switch(Request::path()){}
```

which resolves to about, contact etc.

Another way to go about it would be to use

```
Route::get('{page}', 'PagesController@ShowPage');
```

which will pass the variable in the controller like

```
public function showPage($page){}
```

but be aware that this route will match any path,

if there is not another match above it.

Comment: This is a bad idea, since the page parameter is passed to the function then why he should use `Request::path()` and switch is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

They're already being passed down to the method:

```
public function ShowPage($which){
  switch($which){
   case 'about':
        // do something
        break;
   case 'contact':
        // do something else
        break;
   default:
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm..I only get `Missing argument 1 for PagesController::showPage()`

Comment: Are you getting it when calling one of those routes?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
// In your routes.php (This route will match only this route because of "where")
Route::get('{page}','PagesController@showPage')->where('page', 'about|contact');
```

If you use `http://example.com/about` (or `contact`)  it'll work but with other values it won't work, in other words, this route won't match without `about` or `contact`.

Then in your controller, try this:

```
class PagesController extends BaseController {
    public function showPage($page) {
        // use $page, don't use use switch, $page will be either about or contact
    }
}
```